# How to set numeric variables in vim functions

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a function that calls `setlocal` to set some variables to the param(s) that I pass in. But I'm getting the error `Number required after =: tabstop=...`

```
function! MyFunction(param)
    setlocal tabstop=param
    setlocal tabstop=a:param
endfunction
```

Both lines will fail. Is there some sort of variable interpolation I'm missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to define the option as an `&option` variable. For example:

```
fun! MyFun(param)
   let &l:tabstop = a:param
endfun
```

See `:help let-&`. The `&l:` is listed a little below that tag showing that it is for the equivalent of `setlocal`. Basically, when you want to set an option to an expression instead of a defined value then you need to use `let &option=` instead of `set option=`. Use `let &l:option=` instead of `setlocal option=`. There is also `&g:option` to set the option globally.

Comment: Nice explanation about `&l:` and `&g:`, but `'tabstop'` is local to buffer so there is no need to do a `let &l:tabstop = a:param`, a simple `let &tabstop = a:param` will do.

Comment: Great, thanks @Conner!
  


@PeterRincker ah, but I have to set other vars too. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: Thanks! I spent close to an hour figuring out how to do my first vim function to just set tabstop and shiftwidth in one command.  Now I'm on my way to wasting all day writing vim functions...

Comment: Note that we can also use `:exe` which will be quite cumbersome, and the recent `setbufvar()` function that also permits to set local options in buffers other than the current one which is really handy, when we have this need, to avoid switching buffers.